# как убрать отступ над шрифтом в input

Tags: css, scss

Текст в input (засчет отступа над ним) расположен не по центру. Как убрать отступы у шрифтов?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это особенности шрифта. Попробуйте заменить шрифт или выравнивайте отступами

Answer (score 3):

> Это особенности шрифта. Попробуйте заменить шрифт или выравнивайте отступами
>   **@HamSter**

Допустим шрифт имеет высоту в `16px`, а с отступом он `20px` => вам нужно убрать `4px` отступа сверху, при том, что отступы в инпуте, снизу и сверху = `10px (padding: 10px 0;)`.
В таком случае, решение будет таким:

```
input {
  padding-top: 6px; /* Те самые -4px */
  paddin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Так, визуально, получится что текст вертикально по центру инпута.